# Angular 11, CORS

Tags: cors, angular11

Ошибка при отправке запроса на удаленный сервер

При

```
  getJobs(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://jobs.github.com/positions.json")
  }
```

Видаёт ошибку

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jobs.github.com/positions.json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Если добавить

```
headers: {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
}
```

Ошибка та же.
Как можно пофиксить данный баг?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Решил проблему установкой Google chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Update 2

Так же помогло создание прокси

proxy.config.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://your_domain.com",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

и запуск проекта ng serve -proxy-config=proxy.conf.json